# Changing the color of an element in a ul on click, but keeping it when clicking on an element of another ul

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

there is a task to change the color of the li in the ul, but only in a specific ul, when you click on the li in another ul, the old li is not lost. How to implement this without Id, since UL are output through a loop and there can be an unlimited number of them.

```js
$('.list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li { cursor: pointer; }
li.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not written in English

Comment: Вопросы и ответы здесь должны быть написаны на английском языке. Пожалуйста, используйте http://ru.stackoverflow.com. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use http://ru.stackoverflow.com.)

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: Changing the color of an element in a ul on click, but keeping it when clicking on an element of another ul- Translation of this question

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate your uls in some way. I didn't understand why you can't use Ids but there are other options.

1. add class of list1/list2 and only target the necessary list.

2.You could use :nth-child() in jQuery and CSS.
So if you only wanted the action to occur when clicking on an li of the first ul you would do this:

```js
$('.list:nth-child(1)').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li { cursor: pointer; }
li.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
```